# pic32 write in flash c programming

Tags: c, flash-memory, pic32

I am new to C and PIC programming. I was asked to fix an existing code as it is not working efficiently. I made changes and come up with my own algorithm, however, as I only have some object oriented experience, I think I am missing something fundamental. Here is my code:

```
 BOOL FLASH_Init_Write(){LCD_WriteLine("INIT_WRITE!",1,TRUE);
 char temp_pass[4];
 BOOL returned;     
 BYTE j;
 LCD_WriteLine("In the function",1,TRUE);
 FLASH_ErasePage();   
 LCD_WriteLine("after erase",1,TRUE);     
 char *value="\0";   
 char *value1="1";   
 char *value99="99";
 char *config[1356];
 memset(config,0,1356); 
 char ATN[2448];   
 memset(ATN,0,2448); 
 char BUZ[408]; 
 memset(BUZ,0,408); 
 char REL[408]; 
 memset(REL,0,408); 
 char DTC[408];   
 memset(DTC,0,408); 
 char DTS[8160]; 
 memset(DTS,0,8160); 
 char FNR1[2448]; 
 memset(FNR1,0,2448);       
 char FNR2[2448];   
 memset(FNR2,0,2448);   
 char FNR3[2448];   
 memset(FNR3,0,2448);
 char FNR4[2448];     
 memset(FNR4,0,2448);
 char FNR5[2448];   
 memset(FNR5,0,2448);
 char FNR6[2448];     
 memset(FNR6,0,2448);
 char FNR7[2448];     
 memset(FNR7,0,2448);
 char FNR8[2448];       
 memset(FNR8,0,2448);
 char FNR9[2448];       
 memset(FNR9,0,2448);
 char FNR10[2448];       
 memset(FNR10,0,2448);       
 char FTXT1[10200];       
 memset(FTXT1,0,10200);
 char FTXT2[10200];     
 memset(FTXT2,0,10200);
 char FTXT3[10200];       
 memset(FTXT3,0,10200);
 char FTXT4[10200];       
 memset(FTXT4,0,10200);
 char FTXT5[10200];       
 memset(FTXT5,0,10200);
 char FTXT6[10200];       
 memset(FTXT6,0,10200);
 char FTXT7[10200];       
 memset(FTXT7,0,10200);
 char FTXT8[10200];       
 memset(FTXT8,0,10200);
 char FTXT9[10200];       
 memset(FTXT9,0,10200);
 char FTXT10[10200];       
 memset(FTXT10,0,10200); 

 strncpy(temp_pass,FLASH_Read_Password(),4);
 ClearWDT();
 if(_ONOFF)
 {
    if(!FLASH_SetOnOff(0)) return FALSE;  
 }
 else
 {
    if(!FLASH_SetOnOff(1) ) return FALSE;               
 }
 if (POWERCONNECTION)
 {
    flag_PowerOn = FALSE;
 }
 else  
 {
    flag_PowerOn = TRUE;       
 }
 if(!FLASH_WriteLowBatteryFlag(0)) 
 {
     ERROR_Handling(ERROR_FLASH_WRITING_LOW_BATT);           
     return FALSE;
 }



 //ATN values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings               
 memcpy(&ATN[24],value1,1);       
 memcpy(&ATN[25],value,1);       
 for(j=2;j<100;j++)       
 {         
   memcpy(&ATN[24*j],value,1); 
 }       
 memcpy(&ATN[2400],value1,1);       
 memcpy(&ATN[2401],value,1);       
 memcpy(&ATN[2424],value1,1);       
 memcpy(&ATN[2425],value,1);           
 //BUZZER values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings       
 for(j=1;j<100;j++)       
 {           
    memcpy(&BUZ[4*j],value99,1);

 }       
 //RELAY values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings               
 for(j=1;j<100;j++)       
 {           
    memcpy(&REL[4*j],value99,1);

   }       
 //Display Text Configuration values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings 
  memcpy(&DTC[4],value1,1);       
  memcpy(&DTC[5],value,1);       
  memcpy(&DTC[400],value1,1);       
  memcpy(&DTC[401],value,1);       
  memcpy(&DTC[404],value1,1);       
  memcpy(&DTC[405],value,1);               
 //Display Text String values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings               
 for(j=0;j<102;j++)       
 {           
    memcpy(&DTS[j*80],value,1); 
 } 
   //Forward Number values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings 


 for(j=0;j<102;j++)      
 {           
    memcpy(&FNR1[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT1[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR2[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT2[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR3[j*24],value,1);         
    memcpy(&FTXT3[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR4[j*24],value,1);     
    memcpy(&FTXT4[j*100],value,1);         
    memcpy(&FNR5[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT5[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR6[j*24],value,1);         
    memcpy(&FTXT6[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR7[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT7[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR8[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT8[j*100],value,1);         
    memcpy(&FNR9[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT9[j*100],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FNR10[j*24],value,1);           
    memcpy(&FTXT10[j*100],value,1); 
   }       
 //Forward Text values for all 102 profiles set to factory settings              

//now put together all the configs       

 for(j=0;j<102;j++)       
 {                                 
    memmove(config,&ATN[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[24],&BUZ[4*j],4);           
    memmove(&config[28],&REL[4*j],4);           
    memmove(&config[32],&DTC[4*j],4);           
    memmove(&config[36],&DTS[80*j],80);           
    memmove(&config[116],&FNR1[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[140],&FTXT1[100*j],100);         
    memmove(&config[240],&FNR2[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[264],&FTXT2[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[364],&FNR3[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[388],&FTXT3[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[488],&FNR4[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[512],&FTXT4[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[612],&FNR5[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[636],&FTXT5[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[736],&FNR6[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[760],&FTXT6[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[860],&FNR7[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[884],&FTXT7[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[984],&FNR8[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[1008],&FTXT8[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[1108],&FNR9[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[1132],&FTXT9[100*j],100);           
    memmove(&config[1232],&FNR10[24*j],24);           
    memmove(&config[1256],&FTXT10[100*j],100);                                
 //write configs in flash, one profile at a time 
      if(!FLASH_Write_Default_Config(j,(char*)config)) return FALSE;                                                    } 

 if(flag_externalmode || flag_initwrite)       
 {
    if(!FLASH_Write_MasterNr("\0"))
    {
       ERROR_Handling(ERROR_FLASH_WRITING_MASTERNUMBER);
       return FALSE;          
    }
 }               
 if(!FLASH_Write_OOT(1))
 {  
        ERROR_Handling(ERROR_FLASH_WRITING_OOT);              
        return FALSE;   
 }
 if(!FLASH_Write_Password(temp_pass))return FALSE;                                                return TRUE;}

 BOOL FLASH_Write_Default_Config(BYTE ind, char* value)
 {
 BOOL result;
 char temp[1356]={0};
 strcpy(temp,value);
 result = FLASH_WriteToMemory(RECORD_ADDRESS_00 - 1356*ind, temp, 1356);
 if(result == FALSE)
 {
 ERROR_Handling(ERROR_FLASH_WRITING_RECORD);
 flag_FlashWrtRecordErr=TRUE;
 return FALSE;
 }
 else
 return TRUE;
 }
```

So this code fills up some arrays then puts them together into config[] and then writes it in the flash. Here is a portion of the .h file:

```
#define RECORD_ADDRESS_00                      0xBD07FAB4              // 1356 bytes - unknown number configuration
 //Acc Tel Nr. 01 (24 bytes),Buzzer 01 (4 bytes),Relay 01 (4 bytes),Display Text Cfg 01 (4 bytes),Display Text 01 (80 bytes),
 //Forward Nr 01 01 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 01 (100 bytes),Forward Nr 01 02 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 02 (100 bytes),//Forward Nr 01 03 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 03 (100 bytes),Forward Nr 01 04 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 04    (100 bytes),//Forward Nr 01 05 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 05 (100 bytes),Forward Nr 01 06 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 06 (100 bytes),//Forward Nr 01 07 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 07 (100 bytes),Forward Nr 01 08 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 08 (100 bytes),//Forward Nr 01 09 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 09 (100 bytes),Forward Nr 01 10 (24 bytes),Forward Text 01 10 (100 bytes);
 //1356 bytes = 0x0000054C
  #define RECORD_ADDRESS_01                     0xBD07F568              // 1356 bytes - pushbutton alarm configuration
 #define RECORD_ADDRESS_02                      0xBD07F01C              // 1356 bytes - access number 2 configuration
 #define RECORD_ADDRESS_03                      0xBD07EAD0              // 1356 bytes - access number 3 configuration
 #define RECORD_ADDRESS_04                      0xBD07E584              // 1356 bytes - access number 4 configuration
 #define RECORD_ADDRESS_05                      0xBD07E038              // 1356 bytes - access number 5 configuration
 #define RECORD_ADDRESS_06                      0xBD07DAEC              // 1356 bytes - access number 6 configuration
 #define RECORD_ADDRESS_07                      0xBD07D5A0              // 1356 bytes - access number 7 configuratione
```

One of my biggest concerns is the PageSize here. It is defined as 4096 (PIC32MX460F512L). I'm not sure if I should be writing 4096 byte long data at a time. Please try to help me out here, I have been struggling with this for quite some time now and i can't find that silly mistake I am making.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't randomly indent code. It makes it unreadable.

Comment: It's my first post here, I'm sorry. I hope it's better now

Comment: This: `char *config[1356]; memset(config,0,1356);` should be `unsigned char config[1356]; memset(config, 0, sizeof config);`. Note the dropped `*` and use of `sizeof`.

Comment: This one throws error: syntax error before "size_t" .

Answer (score 0):

Unless your pointers have size 1, objects are not completely zeroed with

```
char *config[1356];
memset(config, 0, 1356);
//  It should be 
memset(config, 0, 1356 * sizeof(char*));
// or better yet
memset(config, 0, sizeof(config));
```

But as @unwind suggests, `config` is the wrong type and you should use

```
char config[1356];  // no *
memset(config, 0, sizeof(config));
```

This applies to many other objects too.

---

How memory is written to flash is compiler dependent, which was not specified.  If in doubt, create a page size buffer (4096), read flash memory into it, copy your updates into the buffer and then write the page.

Instead of `memmove(&config[24],&BUZ[4*j],4);` and the like, consider making a packed `struct` for all these fields.